# Jquery - Return deferred with other objects from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I have a function which look so:

```
function get_modifications_as_objects() {

var deferred = $.Deferred();

//Do stuff.....

return {
    actual_lov_values : actual_lov_values,
    new_lov_values : new_lov_values,
    deleted_lov_values : deleted_lov_values
}

deferred.resolve();
return deferred.promise();  
}
```

And the call to that function is:

```
get_modifications_as_objects()
    .then(function(lov_values_object) {
        console.log(lov_values_object);
    });
```

Of course, in this case, ".then" isn't working because it never gets to the return of my promise. 
So I tried to wrap the two returns into separate functions but I couldn't make it work.

I need to return both the promise and the other object, how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass data using [`deferred.resolve()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) method

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();

//Do stuff.....
deferred.resolve({
    actual_lov_values: actual_lov_values,
    new_lov_values: new_lov_values,
    deleted_lov_values: deleted_lov_values
});
return deferred.promise();
```